# Getting WebBrowser.DocumentText from a WebBrowser-derived class

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, derived-class

I'm trying to write a derived class from System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser to put on it an HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument and automate/add some things WebBrowser does/doesn't.
I've solved most of things but I want to automate the way I'm loading the html into the HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.
WebBrowser doesn't really expose a way of know if it have finished loading and I've used on this derived class the DocumentCompleted event and have put a System.Timers.Timer to raise an event, this way it will reset the timer until the last DocumentCompleted.
I've tried to expose a eventhandler but I want to do it automatically, I don't want need to call xwebBrowser.HAPDocument.LoadHtml(xwebBrowser.DocumentText) from outside...

After some hours spent (just by my fault, I haven't tried it when I must) on doing this class, its extensions, etc... I've tried to run it, and it compiled but when it tried to get the DocumentText it was null...
Now I know DocumentText will be null until it finishes its work.
Is there a way to achieve this or im just wasting time?
Thanks in advance!

I'm sorry if someone doesn't understand me, my English is very poor.

```
public class XWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{    
    public HtmlDocument HAPDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    private Timer loadTimeout = new Timer() { Interval = 1200, AutoReset = false };
    public bool IsLoading { get; private set; }

    public int LoadTimeout
    {   
        get { return (int)loadTimeout.Interval; }
        set { loadTimeout.Interval = value; }
    }

    public XWebBrowser()
    {   
        DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Document_Completed);
        loadTimeout.Elapsed += loadTimeout_Elapsed;
    }

    private void Document_Completed(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("completed");
        IsLoading = true;
        loadTimeout.Reset(); //Just a method what does if (loadTimeout.Enabled) loadTimeout.Stop(); loadTimeout.Start();
    }

    private void loadTimeout_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("loaded");
        IsLoading = false;
        loadTimeout.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(DocumentText); //The problem comes here, a System.Windows.Forms InvalidCastException (DocumentText equals null so cant be casted to string i suppose)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing where your DocumentText  variable is defined.

Comment: Try:

    Action a = () => System.Console.WriteLine(this.DocumentText); 
    if (this.InvokeRequired) this.Invoke(a); else a();

Comment: @ShamilS how i could forget to try that? lol, i have made an extension method to do that a year ago but i havent thought this requires a invoke hehehe, really thx for that. From the beginning of my c# learning this is my prefered comunity to do it, its awesome and i have found everytime what i need, i never need before to register and post my answer.